# TwitterCredentials.SetCredentials from tweetinvi not found

Tags: twitter, tweetinvi

i installed tweetinvi but the TwitterCredentials.SetCredentials is not found.

```
 Install-Package TweetinviAPI
```

How can i solve this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using an old Tweetinvi code.

Tweetinvi break compatibility since version 0.9.9.5. Instead of "TwitterCredentials.SetCredentials" you should now use "Auth.SetUserCredentials"

plaese note that the parameters order has also been changed!

Try this:

```
Auth.SetUserCredentials("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET", "ACCESS_TOKEN", "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET");
```

For more options, see https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Credentials

Comment: Can you please share code sample for posting text (it should popup user to sign in Twitter) to any user?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
TwitterCredentials twitterCredentials = new TwitterCredentials("<consumerKey>", "<consumerSecret>", "<accessToken>", "<token_secret">);
```

Hope this will help.